# Regex for checking the first letter in a string

Tags: java, regex

A regex that will check a word that constructs APPLE from a given input string. An example of this would be "**A** **p**eople see **p**erson **l**eaving for **e**veryone.
So far this is what I have done

```
//        Pattern applePattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+^[aA]?");
//        Matcher outputApple;
//        String apple;
//        do {
//            System.out.print("Enter a string that contructs the word APPLE: ");
//            apple = input.nextLine();
//            outputApple = applePattern.matcher(apple);
//        } while (!outputApple.find());

    String applePattern=("\\w+^[aA]?");
    String outputApple;
    String apple;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a string that contructs the word APPLE: ");
        apple=input.nextLine();
        outputApple=apple.matches(applePattern)?"TRUE":"FALSE";
    }while(outputApple.equals("FALSE"));
```

Also, what do you recommend? The commented code or the other?

EDIT: It's now working as it should.

```
 String applePattern = ("[Aa].*? p.*? p.*? l.*? e\\S*");
    String outputApple;
    String apple;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a string that contructs the word APPLE: ");
        apple = input.nextLine();
        outputApple = apple.matches(applePattern) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
    } while (outputApple.equals("FALSE"));
```

Comment: `[Aa]\w+\s+p\w+\s+p\w+\s+l\w+\s+e`

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Good one but problem is `see` and `for` in OP's input

Comment: What made you come up with the second code? I'd avoid string-comparison ...

Comment: Y that's what booleans are for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you mean this pattern.

```
[Aa].*? p.*? p.*? l.*? e\\S*
```

Code:

```
String s = "A people see person leaving for everyone";
System.out.println(s.matches("[Aa].*? p.*? p.*? l.*? e\\S*")); // true
```

Explanation:

- `[Aa]` Match a capital `A` or small `a`
- `.*?<space>` Match any character upto the  space.
- `p` character following the space would be a letter `p`. Likewise it goes upto the `<space>e`
- `\S*` Match zero or more non-space characters.

Comment: Yes. This works, I would add explanation to make it better answer.

Comment: It matches `Bad p p l e` also, you need `\b` before `[Aa]`

Comment: it's a matches method. It tries to match the whole string.

Comment: I was merely talking about regex not about the way it is used. But +1 for good answer